# RewriteRule loop in .htaccess not working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make pretty links for all the pages in a site,
I'd like `foo.com/services/domestic` to go to `foo.com/index.php?page=services-domestic`. I have the following in my .htaccess file and it's working fine for the above example, but if I try to go to `foo.com/services/domestic/case/1` (expecting `/index.php?page=services-domestic-case-1`) I get a 404.

```
# a/b/c/d -> a-b-c-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1-$2 [N]

# a-b-c-d -> index.php?page=a-b-c-d
RewriteRule ^([^(/|\.)]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

I've tried just repeating the `[N]` line three times without the flag to no avail. It's not working for any but the first depth. Probably just my amateur regex but I can't understand what's breaking, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to tweak your regular expressions and rewrite flags:

```
# a/b/c/d -> a-b-c-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /$1-$2 [L]

# a-b-c-d -> index.php?page=a-b-c-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: yayyy it works! I needed to add the RewriteCond from the answer below though so it didn't mess up any asset urls

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ $1-$2 [N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: this works on 2+ depth, but with the my first example it's returning `?page=services-domestic/domestic`