# .htaccess rewriterule "loop"

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this line in my .htaccess file making URLs "pretty" for pages.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ /directory/?type=page&title=$1 [L]
```

However, I sometimes have sub-pages (`/page/sub-page/sub-page/`), yet this line only supports one level (`/page/`).

How can I alter this code to support sub-pages (any amount) and make the `title` variable something like:

```
&title=page/sub-page/sub-page
```

**/** being the seperator.

I know that this will definitely be a huge help:

[RewriteRule loop in .htaccess not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937409/rewriterule-loop-in-htaccess-not-working)

However, due to my lack of knowledge with regex and mod-rewrite, I don't know how to make it properly work with what I already have.

Comment: Why use `/_/` instead of just the regular `/`? Why not do that replacement in your script instead of trying to make mod_rewrite do something it wasn't meant to do?

Comment: As Jon wrote, you need to clarify what is problem with `&title=page/sub-page/sub-page`?

Comment: @JonLin You're correct, I hadn't really thought it through. Nevertheless, what would be the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some regex research, and doing some testing, it seems like this is the answer to my problem:

```
RewriteRule ^(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/?)+)$ /directory/?type=page&title=$1 [L]
```

I altered my previous code and allowed support for multiple sub-directories. Then I placed it into a capture group and placed that data into the `title` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([/a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /directory/?type=page&title=$1 [NC,B,L]
```

Don't worry about `A-Z` because of the `NC` flag.